# Apache2 cant find pdf file in default directory

Tags: php, apache, pdf, http-status-code-404

so, I have a setup with apache2, php5, Mysql, etc... everything seems to work alright and I'm using default directory `/var/www/html`.
I can upload pdfs into directory `/var/www/html/uploads`, and also display the pdfs uploaded into directory in list of links by using scandir(php method).
I've also checked permissions on the directory, pdf files, and `/etc/mime`.types.

And ofc, the files are there too. I have also tried naming my pdf files with lower case without any special characters.

The error code is 404 Not found:The requested URL `/var/www/html/uploads/cv.pdf` was not found on this server. When I try to download the file, by right-clicking link and downloading, i just get a broken pdf that isnt readable. However, the pdf files seem perfectly fine, since when I scp them back to my local computer and read them they're not broken at all.

Any suggestions on why I may be experiencing this error?
All suggestions and help appreciated.

Comment: just tell how you access your web. by localhost or not

Comment: I have a remote server through digital ocean. Is that what you're asking? If I'm working on it locally or not?